# What does jq '.' do?

Tags: json, jq

How the jq '.' parsing the json and displaying ?

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' | jq '.'
```

I see the json is parsed and diplayed correctly

> What is the implementation behind " xxxx | jq '.' "

How can i understand that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters):

> `.`
>
> The absolute simplest (and least interesting) filter is `.`. This is a filter that takes its input and produces it unchanged as output.
>
> Since `jq` by default pretty-prints all output, this trivial program can be a useful way of formatting JSON output from, say, `curl`.

Comment: For better or worse, jq first parses the JSON, and pretty-prints the parsed version. This means in particular that the initial representation of numbers is lost.

Comment: @peak: What do you mean by "the initial representation of numbers"?

Comment: The input representation.  Consider what happens, for example, to 1.0e1000

Comment: @peak: I did wonder if that's what you meant. Since it's the same number either way, it doesn't make any difference. If you just want to dump the contents, don't use `jq`; use `cat` or (Windows) `type`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In the jq programming language, `.` refers to the implicit input of a filter. For example, `def f: .;` defines a function `f` that outputs its implicit input as-is.

Note that, inside filter arguments, the filter can change what `.` refers to: for example, `map(f)` is defined as `[.[] | f]`; on the jq program `[1, 2, 3] | map(. + 1)`, `.` refers to each of the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `jq .` pretty-printing the output, it also produces a warning if the input file cannot be parsed. As such it is handy for testing unknown JSON files to see if the source file has syntax issues.